# How to make LinqPad SQL Window return constants?

Tags: sql, linq, enums, constants, linqpad

I have this LinQ query:

```
Customers.Select (c => new { 
Customer_id = c.Customer_id,
Customer_name = c.Customer_name,
Customer_Campaign = 5,
Customer_Type = "Good!",
})
```

Why is it that the SQL Translation showed in the SQL Window is:

```
SELECT [t0].[Customer_id] AS [Customer_id], [t0].[Customer_name] AS [Customer_name]
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
```

...Totally ignoring my constants!

I think LinqPad is the best tool ever, and i use it everyday but i also need to do some SQL translations and this is blowing my mind!

Comment: Its not ignoring your constants. You have to understand Linq (to EF) is not for creating SQL for your own usage, it is for creating SQL for getting what you asked for. You only asked for `customer_id` and `customer_name` from the database. So the SQL only asks for those. When EF gets those back, it applies/binds the constants to your anonymous class/object.

Comment: But the SQL translation of LinqPad is a nice tool to use!

Does that means that i can only trust that SQL translation when is dealing with table fields only? What if i use CASE, or ( ? : ) for processing the values in my queries? In the Lambda Tab the constant values are correctly resolved.

How does that translation actually works? I would like to figure it out or some workaround...
And hey, thanks for your quick answer... :)

Comment: No it means that the SQL it generates is not for you. As for how the translation works...The actual IQueryable has a Expression tree in it, you can access that in the Expression property. On IQueryable.Execute, the IQueryProvider converts the Expression tree into (in EF's case some SQL) a function. As for how the Expression tree gets converted into SQL...that is highly highly complex.

Answer (score 0):

Your constants does't go from SQL Server. LinqToSQL converts only that you need to get from DB. Nothing more. Your constants is local C# strings. No need to transfer them from DB.